# Disable other rules by use of a custom Roslyn Analyzer

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm implementing a custom Roslyn Analyzer whose ruleset would override a currently existing rule shipped by default with Visual Studio. Is there some way to make my rule silence this other rule in specific scenarios?

I haven't so far been able to find any documentation on whether this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! This is possible via implementing a [DiagnosticSuppressor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.diagnosticsuppressor), available since *Roslyn 3.3.1*, that you could add alongside your [DiagnosticAnalyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.diagnosticanalyzer).
Actually, *DiagnosticSuppressor* derives from *DiagnosticAnalyzer*, and could look something like this:

```cs
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
internal sealed class MyDiagnosticSuppressor : DiagnosticSuppressor
{
    private static readonly SuppressionDescriptor Rule = new(
        "My-Diagnostic-Suppressor-Id",
        "Suppressed-Diagnostic-Id",
        "Justification / Description."
    );

    public override ImmutableArray<SuppressionDescriptor> SupportedSuppressions
        => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void ReportSuppressions(SuppressionAnalysisContext context)
    {
        foreach (var diagnostic in context.ReportedDiagnostics)
        {
            Location location = diagnostic.Location;
            SyntaxTree? syntaxTree = location.SourceTree;
            SyntaxNode root = syntaxTree.GetRoot(context.CancellationToken);
            TextSpan textSpan = location.SourceSpan;
            SyntaxNode node = root.FindNode(textSpan);
            SemanticModel semanticModel = context.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

            if (ShouldSuppress(context.Compilation, semanticModel, node, context.CancellationToken))
            {
                Suppression suppression = Suppression.Create(Rule, diagnostic);
                context.ReportSuppression(suppression);
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool ShouldSuppress(Compilation compilation, SemanticModel semanticModel, SyntaxNode node, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Also, I've recently built a *DiagnosticSuppressor*, which suppresses [CA1707](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1707) (Identifiers should not contain underscores) on [MSTest](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx), [NUnit](https://github.com/nunit/nunit) and [xUnit.net](https://github.com/xunit/xunit) test methods. Here's that [Pull Request](https://github.com/Flash0ver/F0.Analyzers/pull/97/files#diff-9ad44a8422c67f591c7fe80a740c89572bd0721140c185b7f08d6e4ffbe99d05), including unit tests and benchmarks. Perhaps it proves useful to you.